# How to use Position:fixed; and slideDown() together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

slideDown() animation not working with position:fixed div
How to use both together?
Is it possible?

My css:

```
.ham{
  position: fixed; 
  top: 50px; 
  left: 0; 
  z-index: 100;

  /* Preserve aspet ratio */
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(210,10,10);
  display: none;
}
```

My Js

```
$(function()
        {

             $( "#hb" ).click(function() {
                console.log("toggle");
                    $("#ham").slideDown("slow");
                    $("#hb").fadeOut();
                    $("#cb").fadeIn();
                 return false;
             }); 

             $( "#cb" ).click(function() {
                console.log("toggle");
                    $("#ham").slideUp("slow");
                    $("#hb").fadeIn();
                    $("#cb").fadeOut();
                 return false;
             }); 
        });
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="ham" id="ham">


    </div>
    <a href="#" id="hb"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger back_button"></span></a>
    <a href="#" id="cb" style="display: none"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove back_button"></span></a>
    .
    .
    .
    .
    </body>
```

slideDown() animation not working with position:fixed div
How to use both together?
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simple CSS and small tweaks on JS can do the trick.

**CSS**

```
.ham{
    position: fixed; 
    top: 50px; 
    left: 0; 
    z-index: 100;

    /* Preserve aspet ratio */
    min-width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(210,10,10);
    min-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 500ms;
}
.opened {
    overflow: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function()
{
    $( "#hb" ).click(function() {
        console.log("toggle");
        $("#ham").addClass("opened");
        $("#hb").fadeOut();
        $("#cb").fadeIn();
        return false;
    }); 

    $( "#cb" ).click(function() {
        console.log("toggle");
        $("#ham").removeClass("opened");
        $("#hb").fadeIn();
        $("#cb").fadeOut();
        return false;
    }); 
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u5zavnxm/

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own animation with setInterval and move with fixed element pixel by pixel with for examlpe

```
variable=curret div position top;

setInterval(function()
  {

   $("#fixedelement").css("top",""variable);
   variable = variable+nuber of pixel you want to move;
  },10);
```

After reach position you want you will clear Interval and stop function